# Configurable and simple products listing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing a classic t-shirts store.

I’ve created the products as configurable products (for example “Some Cool T Shirt” and “Another T Shirt") and then i’ve created simple products associated to the configurable product for example:

- Some Cool T Shirt RED SIZE L
- Some Cool T Shirt RED SIZE M
- Some Cool T Shirt YELLOW SIZE L
- Another T Shirt BLUE SIZE M
- Another T Shirt BLUE SIZE S

The trouble that I have is that my client wants to show in product lists every product by colour.

But I don’t know how to handle this. Because if I set simple products visibility to catalog I will have in the product listing “Some Cool T Shirt RED SIZE L” AND also “Some Cool T Shirt RED SIZE M”. But I just want ONE red Some Cool T Shirt in listing.

The other thing that thinked is to create this configurable products:

“Some Cool T Shirt RED” 
“Some Cool T Shirt YELLOW” 
...

And that the simple products just have the size attribute. But the problem that I have with this approach is that in the product view the customer only can select size attribute, but cant select the color attribute.

Do you have any idea how can I handle something like this?

Comment: You can have that list (of colors products) with $this->_productCollection->groupByAttribute('color'); in class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List' and method '_getProductCollection'. of course you should do this by extendig/overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've used in the past was to create a widget that displays the attribute values of each of the products that are included in the configurable product. For example if you have two attributes: color and size, the widget could be designed to display something (content and formatting are up to you) as:

These T-shirts are available in:

Colors: Red, Yellow, etc.

Sizes: S, M, L, XL

This does nothing to list the products as individual products (which would seem to be very confusing for the customer). But, it does add all the attribute values to the content for each product which could be a benefit to the customer (and possibly for SEO).

Comment: So what yo did is to list simple products (ie: Some Cool T Shirt RED SIZE L and Some Cool T Shirt YELLOW SIZE L) and in the product view page get the configurable product and list it attributes?

Comment: There was no listing of simple products. All the simple products are set to not be displayed. The widget gets the attributes that are used for the configurable product, then gets the values for those attributes (e.g. size=>S, M, L, XL and color=>Red, Blue, White). Then it formats that attribute information within the configurable product's product short description.